# Grouping php arrays and showing highest and lowest value in the array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have an array that looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 19.0001.2
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 1
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 19.0001.2
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 2
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 19.0001.2
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 3
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 19.0001.2
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 4
        )
    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 19.0001.2
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 5
        )
    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => 19.0001.2
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 6
        )
    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => 19.0001.2
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 7
        )
    [7] => Array
        (
            [0] => 19.0001.2
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 8
        )
    [8] => Array
        (
            [0] => 19.0001.2
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 9
        )
    [9] => Array
        (
            [0] => 19.0001.2
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 10
        )
    [10] => Array
        (
            [0] => 19.0001.2
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 11
        )
    [11] => Array
        (
            [0] => 19.0001.2
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 12
        )
    [12] => Array
        (
            [0] => 19.0001.2
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 20
        )
    [13] => Array
        (
            [0] => 19.0001.2
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 21
        )
    [14] => Array
        (
            [0] => 19.0001.2
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 22
        )
    [15] => Array
        (
            [0] => 19.0001.2
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 23
        )
    [16] => Array
        (
            [0] => 19.0001.2
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 24
        )
    [17] => Array
        (
            [0] => 19.0001.2
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 25
        )
    [18] => Array
        (
            [0] => 19.0001.2
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 26
        )
   [19] => Array
        (
            [0] => 19.0001.2
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 27
        )
    [20] => Array
        (
            [0] => 19.0001.2
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 33
        )
    [21] => Array
        (
            [0] => 19.0001.2
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 30
        )
    [22] => Array
        (
            [0] => 19.0001.2
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 35
        )
    [23] => Array
       (
            [0] => 19.0001.2
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 46
        )
    [24] => Array
        (
            [0] => 19.0001.2
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 47
        )
    [25] => Array
        (
            [0] => 19.0001.2
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 48
        )
    [26] => Array
        (
            [0] => 19.0001.2
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 50
        )
    [27] => Array
        (
            [0] => 19.0001.2
            [1] => 3
            [2] => 1
        )
    [28] => Array
        (
            [0] => 19.0001.3
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 40
        )
    [29] => Array
        (
            [0] => 19.0001.3
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 41
        )
    [30] => Array
        (
            [0] => 19.0001.3
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 42
        )
    [31] => Array
        (
            [0] => 19.0001.3
            [1] => 3
            [2] => 7
        )
    [32] => Array
        (
            [0] => 19.0001.3
            [1] => 3
            [2] => 8
        )
    [33] => Array
        (
            [0] => 19.0001.3
            [1] => 3
            [2] => 9
        )
    [34] => Array
       (
            [0] => 19.0001.3
            [1] => 3
            [2] => 13
        )
    [35] => Array
        (
            [0] => 19.0001.3
            [1] => 4
            [2] => 41
        )
    [36] => Array
       (
            [0] => 19.0001.4
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 2
        )
    [37] => Array
        (
            [0] => 19.0001.4
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 3
        )
    [38] => Array
        (
            [0] => 19.0001.4
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 4
        )
    [39] => Array
        (
            [0] => 19.0001.8
            [1] => 4
            [2] => 40
        )
    [40] => Array
        (
            [0] => 19.0009.8
            [1] => 3
            [2] => 8
        )
)
```

I have a function that groups the last value in an array into a range of numbers, however it doesn't work with the above array. I have tried a number of different arrays with no success. The above array is generated by a mysql query result.

```php
$getlocations = $db->query("
    SELECT barcode
         , test_num
         , magnum
         , sect
         , slidenum 
      FROM fas_log 
     WHERE barcode LIKE '%$bcinv' 
       AND notes = '$notes' 
       AND removed = '$removed' 
       AND staffid= '$sid' 
  ORDER BY magnum, sect, slidenum
  ");
    while ($getlocationsrow = $getlocations->fetch()) {
        extract($getlocationsrow);
        $magrange[]=array("$magnum", "$sect", "$slidenum");
    }

function rangeslides($arr) {
    $previous = null; 
    $result = array();
    $consecutiveArray = array();
    // Slice array by consecutive sequences
    foreach($arr as $number) {
        if ($number == $previous + 1) {
            $consecutiveArray[] = $number;
        } else {
            $result[] = $consecutiveArray;
            $consecutiveArray = array($number);
        }
        $previous = $number;
    }
    $result[] = $consecutiveArray;
    // Get length of each sub array
    $count = array_map('count', $result);
    $first = reset($count);
    $last = end($count);
    prettyarray($result);
}
```

I want to extract data from the array to look like this showing the first and last numbers in the range:
19.0001.2 1 - 12

The above array should produce 15 different results with 9 of them showing no range of numbers because they are singular. 
ie: 19.0001.8 4 40

Comment: how this question is related  to mysql ??'?

Comment: The array is generated by mysql and the solution might be to generate a different array through mysql that is easier to manage.

Comment: then you should add  a proper data sample  .you query code, .your actual result  and   the expected  result  .. as  tabular text  ..  (not array only )

Comment: Sorry not familiar with tabular text but I have added the query if that helps...

Comment: For `19.0001.2` where does the `1` and `12` come from in the array and why?

Comment: There are 12 chronological results associated with 19.0001.2 1. I don't want to show the numbers between 1 and 12. Think of the first two numbers as coordinates to a location with the last number as a number that quanifies the number of objects in that coordinate. I want to group the first two numbers and present a range instead of all the numbers associated with that group.

Comment: Give us an example of what the end product should look like

Comment: Box: 19.0001.2 Section: 1 Item(s): 1 -12

Comment: I have plans on adding the bind_param() function to prevent injections once all the framework is all layed out.